# What is the smallest possible angle of this polygon?

Tags: geometry, convex-analysis, euclidean-geometry

A convex polygon contains a square with side-length 1 and is contained in a parallel square with side-length 2 (which is its smallest containing square). What is the smallest possible angle of the polygon? What is its smallest possible area?

After some playing around with GeoGebra, I found out that in both cases the minimal value is achieved when the contained square is in a corner of the containing square, so the minimal angle is (probably) 36:

[image]

and the minimal area is (probably) 1.5:

[image]

How can I prove that these are indeed the minimal values? Or are they?

NOTE: If the polygon is not required to be convex, then obviously its area can be anywhere from 1 to 4 and its angles can be arbitrarily small. So this question is an attempt to quantify the effects of convexity.

Comment: I agree with the minimum angle but I disagree with the minimum area you obtained; which, in my opinion, should be $1$.

Comment: @heropup I corrected the question. Is this true now?

Comment: do you mean the two squeres are in the exaxt position as in the picture? because,in the second picture,the containing squere is much smaller if rotating the polygon

Comment: The contained square and the containing square are parallel; I added a clarification.

Comment: Why isn't the smallest-area polygon simply the small square itself (area $1$)?

Comment: @Blue because then the smallest containing polygon weren't of size 2. I add a clarification.

Comment: @ErelSegalHalevi: I'm similarly confused about why the minimum area isn't 1. A square is convex, hence a polygon equal to the inner square will be a convex polygon with area 1. If you mean that the polygon must be _exactly_ contained in the larger square, you should specify "exactly". And in this case, your solution for smallest area is incorrect (since the polygon isn't exactly contained in the larger square).

Comment: As for proving the minimum angle, I would break it down into two steps: 1) given $x$ and $y$ that are the offset of the inner square's bottom left corner from the containing square's bottom left corner, compute the piecewise function $\theta _{\min}\left( x, y\right)$ that is the smallest convex polygon angle assuming the given inner square coordinates. 2) Once you've computed this function, optimize over all $\left( x,y\right)$.

Comment: @COTO I mean that the smallest square containing the polygon has a side-length of 2.

Comment: As currently written, I would interpret the phrase "which is its smallest containing square" to mean that there is no other square (even among squares not parallel to the inner square) that is smaller than the stipulated square. I think you mean to say "which is the smallest square that is both parallel to the given unit square _and_ contains the polygon."

Answer (score 3):

***The polygon with the least possible area :-***

**Conditions**

1. The polygon must contain the **1*1** square wholly
2. The polygon must be contained in the **2 by 2** square in a way that this square is the smallest square containing the polygon

**Deduction**

1. The polygon must have more sides = **1** unit, so as to be of the least possible area, and accommodate the small square as well (it must *wrap* the small square). *If the polygon has to be contained in the 2*2 square, it must **just wrap** around the small square*

*These conditions lead us to something like this:*

[image]

All these convex polygons have the same area = 1.5 units , because **triangles with same base and lying between same parallel lines have equal area, as their height is also equal**

If we consider the polygon given in possibility 3 or 4 below, these polygons already have 1.5 sq. units area.

In possibility 3 (below), $\frac{BE*EA}{2}= 0.75$ Therefore total area = 1.75

In possibility 4 (below), $\frac{CE*EA}{2}= 1$ Therefore total area = 2

**Therefore, the polygons with least area = the ones in the first picture, with area = 1.5 sq. units**

**NOTE**

Regarding the NOTE in your question, Even if the polygon is concave, its minimum area needs to be more than 1 sq. units.

### Procedure for the smallest angle:-

Three angles will always be 90 or more than 90, so we focus on the 4th angle.

**Possibility 1**,

[image]

The angle has to be 45 (consider the triangle ABC in first figure. if one angle is 90, other 2 must be 45)

**Possibility 2**

[image]

$AD=\frac{1}{4}units$

In isosceles triangle ABC, BC = 1 and AD=$\frac{1}{4}$

Let $\angle BAE= \angle A$

$\tan A = \frac{BE}{AE} = 0.5$

$A = \tan^{-1}0.5$ ; $A=26.5650 $

$2A = \angle CAB = 53.130$

We see that when the triangle in possibility 2 that when the triangle in the polygon lying outside the small square is DBC, the angle is 45. As the triangle transforms, or as we move the apex of the triangle to a point halfway between D and F, the angle starts increasing until finally it is 53.13 at A. then again it starts decreasing till it reaches F, it again becomes 45. What happens next?

**Possibility 3**

[image]

The angle formed on the side of the square starts decreasing to below 45

here, $AD=\frac{3}{4}units$

$\tan \angle CAG = \frac{\frac{1}{4}}{2} = \frac{1}{8} =0.125$

$\angle CAG= \tan^{-1} 0.125= 7.1256$

and

$\tan \angle BAE=\frac{1.5}{1}=1.5$

$\angle BAE= \tan^{-1}1.5 = 56.3099$

Therefore

$ \angle BAC = 56.3099-7.1256 = 49.1843 $

**Possibility 4**

[image]

Again here, the angle further decreases, till it reaches A. Now, the angle's value is least of all.

In right triangle ADC, CD = $\frac{\sqrt 2}{2}$ and AD= $\sqrt 8 - \frac{\sqrt 2}{2}$

$\tan A = \frac{\frac{\sqrt 2}{2}}{\sqrt 8 - \frac{\sqrt 2}{2}}$ ($\angle A=\angle CAD$)

$\tan A= 0.3333...$

$A = \tan^{-1}0.333...$ ; $A=18.4349 $

$2A = \angle CAB = 36.86989764$

Answer (score 0):

HINT: Assume that the angle is less than your calculated smallest angle and demonstrate that the point will have to lie outside the containing square.